# Sorting pairs of lines based on a single field in one of those lines

Tags: bash, shell, sed, bsd

I'm trying to transform a stream like:

```
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC
http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD
http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery
http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
```

Into:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD
http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery
http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC
http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
```

...by sorting on the second comma-separated field of the lines that start with `#`, while reordering the other lines alongside the ones with the sort keys.

So I would only perform the sort on lines containing the "#EXTINF" and sort from after the ",". It should also keep the line below (URL line) the sorted line with it.

Comment: Could you expand your example to include some lines that shouldn't be sorted and should go separately?

Comment: Sorting "from a character" is easy. Sorting only sections of a file and leaving other parts alone is much harder. This should probably be split into two separate questions. And the input data *definitely* needs to illustrate more of the question (if that question can't be simplified). As it is, this as a rather excessively broad question without an adequate reproducer.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will be only one at most line for each key within a given section? That is to say, is it guaranteed that there won't be more than one line in "From" with the key "hat"?

Comment: Your specification is contradictory/nonsensical. The line containing `bed` moved, and did *not* carry the preceding line with it, as required.

Comment: I updated the example. There could be several lines with "hat". I'm not concerned with how those are ordered, I would just like those to be together.

Comment: I've tried to simplify the question, taking out all the English-language prose that wasn't supported by the example input and output, and removing the original (more confusing) example. (This kind of gross surgery is generally frowned on when there are answers it would invalidate, but since the only answer not self-deleted focuses on only the updated sample input, that's less of a concern here).

Comment: The English-language text implies that lines that neither contain or directly beneath `#EXTINF` are possible in the input, and that if such lines do exist they should be unmodified. Is this genuinely a requirement? (If so, it makes your problem a much harder one).

Answer (score 1):

Transform your data into an easily-sorted format, then sort it back. So:

```
to_one_line_per_record() {
  local inf_line= line=
  while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = "#"* ]]; then
      inf_line=$line
    else
      printf '%s\n' "${inf_line},$line"
    fi
  done
}

from_one_line_per_record() {
  local inf_f1 inf_f2 url
  while IFS=, read -r inf_f1 inf_f2 url; do
    printf '%s,%s\n%s\n' "$inf_f1" "$inf_f2" "$url"
  done
}

to_one_line_from_record | sort -t, -k2,2 | from_one_line_per_record
```

---

With your given input, the output of `to_one_line_per_record` is:

```
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC,http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD,http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery,http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
```

Passing that through `sort -t, -k2,2`, the output becomes:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD,http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery,http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC,http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
```

And passing *that* through `from_one_line_per_record`, it transforms out to:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD
http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery
http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC
http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't really understand what the actual code is doing as such, but from your example I can see its doing what I want. However even my edited example is actually "bad". This is how it could be

#EXTINF:-1 blabla123,Chanel 5
http://aStreamURL123.ts

There can and will be URLs in the top line before the comma. I would only like to sort from after the comma.Thanks

Comment: A place to start in understanding the code above is [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). While often we'll ask folks to ask a new/different question if their original question was correctly answered (but wasn't sufficiently representative of their real problem), feel free to edit the question to have a *real* example, and ping me when it's ready.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look there. I edited it with "real" examples. I didn't share the URLs though because they are private. I wasn't able to try what you posted though because I'm not sure how I point it at my file. I am new to text based code and what I figured out on my own is very simple. I basically download some files, remove some garbage entries and join files together. I have experience with the Unreal Engine's visual scripting which has helped me understand a surprising amount of text based stuff, but it still confuses me. Thanks, Chris

Comment: I updated the answer with the output from your new code. Frankly, this looks right to me as-is (I didn't need to make any code changes to get that output). What's the contrary behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one using GNU awk's `asort`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="," }                     # define , as field separator
{
    p=( NR%2 ? $2 : p )              # every other record updates p
    a[p]=a[p] (a[p]==""?"":ORS) $0   # second record in pair is appended to
}                                    # first ORS separated
END {
    n=asort(a,b,"@ind_str_asc")      # sort on key
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)                # loop them
        print b[i]                   # and output
}' file
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD
http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery
http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC
http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
```

<s>It supports only unique keys in `$2`</s> Is groups records with equal `$2` but does not order within that group, for example:

```
$ awk '{...}' file file
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD
http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD
http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery
http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery
http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC
http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC
http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
```

Comment: The only caveat with sorting internally to `awk` is that it won't automatically spool out to on-disk files (and then combine them via merge support) when handling content too large to fit in memory, as GNU sort will. Unlikely to be a problem here, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Similar in structure to the answer from @Charles, but uses small `awk` scripts instead of the bash functions.

Save the following in its own file, named (for example) sortem.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

[[ $# -ge 1 ]] && exec < "$1"

awk -F , '/^#EXTINF/ {s=$0} /^http/ {print s FS $0}' | \
  sort -t , -k 2,2 | \
  awk -F , '{print $1 FS $2 "\n" $3}'
```

Make the file executable via:

```
$ chmod +x sortem.sh
```

Identify the file where the input to be processed is saved. For example, you might save it in a file named `sortem_input.txt`. Using `cat` to display this file's contents shows:

```
$ cat sortem_input.txt
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC
http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD
http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery
http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
```

Process this input using an invocation like:

```
$ ./sortem.sh sortem_input.txt
```

...or:

```
$ ./sortem.sh < sortem_input.txt
```

...or more generally:

```
$ <commands that generate input> | ./sortem.sh
```

The output looks like:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://randomUrl.com/icon.png",ABC HD
http://StreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://YetAnotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",Discovery
http://DisStreamUrl.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 1-Tv" tvg-logo="http://anotherRandomUrl.com/icon.png",NBC
http://AnotherStreamUrl.m3u8
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I don't want to seem like an idiot, but I kind of am, I'm new :) How do I point this logic at the file I want to edit?

Comment: Editing answer, providing more detail on its usage.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually came up with my own method that works too. `#Join lines at "http"
sed -i '' '$!N;s/\n\s*http/http/;P;D' file.m3u #Sort lines by string after first ","
sort -f -t , -k 2,2 file.m3u -o file.m3u

#Seperate lines again
sed -i '' 's/)http/)\
http'"$1/g" file.m3u` Not sure if its as good as yours?

Comment: Code in comments is hard to read, but your approach looks perfectly reasonable. You've likely noticed the common theme to answers here: (1) join lines, (2) sort joined lines, (3) split lines back out. I suspect the size of the input for this task will always be small, so correct and maintainable (do you understand it? could you fix it if/when the input format changes?) matters more than fast.